# Fix problem in column with cumulative data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a problem with a column in pandas, from a time series, that contains a cumulative sum. On some occasions, the data is wrong for some days, because suddenly the sum appears as 0 and it is not the correct value. An example:

[image: Wrong]

For a single day, I correct this problem with:

```
df_mi["cumsum"].loc["2017-01-04"].expanding().apply(max)
```

[image: OK]

But I am not able to apply this solution for all days of the time series. I have tried the following statement:

```
df_mi["cumsum"].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).expanding().apply(max)
```

But I got the following error:

> IndexError: index 365 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 365

What can I do to fix this problem? Thanks in advance

*Edit*

(p_ac_ist and cum_sum are not related)

Sample data:

```
                         p_ac_ist         cum_sum
    date                                  
2017-01-03 07:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 07:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 07:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 07:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 08:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 08:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 08:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 08:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 09:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 09:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 09:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 09:45:00  168.933333       14.533333
2017-01-03 10:00:00  182.400000       68.066667
2017-01-03 10:15:00  231.066667      122.266667
2017-01-03 10:30:00  202.200000      186.000000
2017-01-03 10:45:00  250.733333      245.000000
2017-01-03 11:00:00  301.133333      318.666667
2017-01-03 11:15:00  235.928571      385.500000
2017-01-03 11:30:00  257.133333      451.000000
2017-01-03 11:45:00  278.800000      517.800000
2017-01-03 12:00:00  241.500000      575.300000
2017-01-03 12:15:00  223.727273      617.727273
2017-01-03 12:30:00  183.133333      663.000000
2017-01-03 12:45:00  170.866667      708.200000
2017-01-03 13:00:00   81.076923      738.923077
2017-01-03 13:15:00  256.133333      785.666667
2017-01-03 13:30:00  189.933333      854.333333
2017-01-03 13:45:00  106.066667      881.200000
2017-01-03 14:00:00  236.454545      925.818182
2017-01-03 14:15:00  230.066667      978.400000
2017-01-03 14:30:00  242.600000     1043.866667
2017-01-03 14:45:00  257.733333     1107.000000
2017-01-03 15:00:00  265.692308     1169.615385
2017-01-03 15:15:00  266.800000     1234.733333
2017-01-03 15:30:00  244.533333     1300.333333
2017-01-03 15:45:00  216.000000     1359.800000
2017-01-03 16:00:00  186.461538     1410.000000
2017-01-03 16:15:00  211.200000     1457.533333
2017-01-03 16:30:00  222.733333     1519.200000
2017-01-03 16:45:00  157.200000     1569.333333
2017-01-03 17:00:00  102.416667     1598.666667
2017-01-03 17:15:00   60.933333     1617.933333
2017-01-03 17:30:00   17.000000     1627.571429
2017-01-03 17:45:00  438.066667     1629.000000
2017-01-03 18:00:00    0.000000     1629.000000
2017-01-03 18:15:00    0.000000     1629.000000
2017-01-03 18:30:00    0.000000     1629.000000
2017-01-03 18:45:00    0.000000     1629.000000
2017-01-03 19:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 19:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 19:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 19:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 20:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 20:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 20:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 20:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 21:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 21:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 21:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 21:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 22:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 22:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 22:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 22:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 23:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 23:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 23:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-03 23:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 00:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 00:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 00:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 00:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 01:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 01:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 01:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 01:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 02:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 02:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 02:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 02:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 03:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 03:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 03:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 03:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 04:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 04:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 04:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 04:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 05:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 05:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 05:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 05:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 06:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 06:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 06:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 06:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 07:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 07:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 07:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 07:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 08:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 08:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 08:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 08:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 09:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 09:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 09:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 09:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 10:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 10:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 10:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 10:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 11:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 11:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 11:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 11:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 12:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 12:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 12:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 12:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 13:00:00  187.923077       14.384615
2017-01-04 13:15:00  186.000000       46.333333
2017-01-04 13:30:00  239.333333       85.466667
2017-01-04 13:45:00  251.000000      148.400000
2017-01-04 14:00:00  176.466667      210.400000
2017-01-04 14:15:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 14:30:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 14:45:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 15:00:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 15:15:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 15:30:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 15:45:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 16:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 16:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 16:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 16:45:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 17:00:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 17:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 17:30:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 17:45:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 18:00:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 18:15:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 18:30:00    0.000000      228.000000
2017-01-04 18:45:00    0.000000      348.800000
2017-01-04 19:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 19:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 19:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 19:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 20:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 20:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 20:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 20:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 21:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 21:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 21:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 21:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 22:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 22:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 22:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 22:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 23:00:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 23:15:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 23:30:00    0.000000        0.000000
2017-01-04 23:45:00    0.000000        0.000000
```

Comment: Hi Miguel Angel, do you mind to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I added an example with data from two days

Comment: `df_mi["cumsum"].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).cummax()`?